# Is there another way besides $V = k\int dq/r$ to find potential?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electrostatics

> Suppose that the charge distribution $q(r)$ in the radial $r$-direction in a thin hollow disc of inner radius $a$ and outer radius $b$ is given by the power-law equation:
>
> $$q(r) = Q_0 \left[1 + \mu\left(\frac{r-a}{r-b}\right)\right]^n$$
>
> where $Q_0$ is magnitude of the charge at $r = a$ and is a constant, while $\mu$ is called the charge-variation parameter which can either be positive of negative; whereas $n$ is the power-law exponent.
> *
> For $n = 2$, what is the electric potential $V (r)$ at any distance $r$ between the inner and outer radii? Also, how is $V (r)$ affected by the variation of $q(r)$ as you move from $r = a$ to $r = b$, related to the variation of $\mu$? What would happen if $n$ is increased?

Basically, all I know about relating $Q$ and $V$ is through:
$$V(r) = k \int \frac{dq}{r}$$

But I'm not confident enough that this would be the right choice. Are there any other approaches other than what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

If you can find an appropriate symmetry, you can use Gauss's law to calculate the electric field, and then compute the potential by integrating $\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}$ along a path starting from a point of known potential. (Probably, from infinity.)

In this particular problem, though, I don't think that will work. There is a circular symmetry, but the behavior of the electric field along the perpendicular dimension isn't known, so you can't really use Gauss's law productively here.